# Vector implementation problems

Tags: arrays, rust, compiler-errors, wrapper, traits

I’m trying to write a mathematical vector library in rust, but I’ve encountered some problems I really want to solve. There are two issues I want to address:

- the “*`Sized` is not implemented for `[T]`*” error
- making the `element` of `Vecor<T>` dense

### Minimal working example

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector<T> {
    elements: [T]
}

// multiple base trait implementations
impl<T> /* … */ for Vector<T> { }


// one of multiple macros
macro_rules! impl_vector_normal_arithmetic {
    ($(impl $trait:ident for Vector { $function:ident($symbol:tt) })+) => {
        $(
            //            ———————— Error: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[T]`
            //            vvvvvv
            impl<T : Num> $trait for Vector<T> {
                type Output = Self;
            
                #[inline(always)]
                fn $function(&self, other: Self) -> Self {
                    Self::new(
                        self.iter()
                            .zip(other.iter())
                            .map(|(&lhs, &rhs)| lhs $symbol rhs)
                            .collect()
                    )
                }
            }
        )+
    };
}

impl_vector_normal_arithmetic! {
    impl Add for Vector { add(+) }
    impl Sub for Vector { sub(-) }
    impl Mul for Vector { mul(*) }
    impl Div for Vector { div(/) }
}
```

### the “*`Sized` is not implemented for `[T]`*” error

My implementation of a vector consists of a generic vector definition that, theoretically, should be able to contain infinitely large vectors. These vectors can only be instantiated once given a size - which implies the use of the array. A macro is then used to add some arithmetic features (Add, Sub, Div, Mul, et cetera). Yet, this causes a problem. I cannot implement those functions, because the compiler tells me that `[T]` does not implement the `Sized` trait. I do understand what the error tells me, but I do know how to tell the compiler that it doesn’t matter what the size is (because the function doesn’t care). What can I do to get around this compiler error?

### making the `elements` of `Vecor<T>` dense

My `Vector<T>` struct contains / can be defined by `elements` of type `[T]`. Yesterday, I was reading up on some memory allocation and came across sparse and dense memory allocation. I was wondering if the array defined by Rust is dense (id est all items are allocated in sequential in (virtual) memory), because that’s what I want to achieve with these vector definitions.

Comment: If you want to provide additional operations over a vector, the by far easiest way to do it is through composition: `struct Vector<T> { inner: Vec<T> }`. That way you still get to define your own traits on `Vector<T>`, but the inner `Vec<T>` is handling allocation and other low-level concerns. And thanks to inlining and zero-cost abstractions, the result is no slower than just using the vector, and will compile to the exact same code. And yes, Rust's arrays, slices, and vectors all have their elements contiguous in memory, i.e. they're dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These vectors can only be instantiated once given a size - which implies the use of the array.

But you have not written an array; you have written a *slice*, which means run-time choice of size, not generic choice of size. `[T]` has a dynamic size; therefore `Vector<T>` has a dynamic size; therefore `Vector<T>` cannot be passed or returned on the stack, and must always be handled behind some pointer. This is probably not what you want.

To declare an array, you must write the type `[T; N]`, not `[T]`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector<T, const N: usize> {
    elements: [T; N]
}
```

This way, `Vector` will always be `Sized`, avoiding the error you asked about. You will need to make your existing generic code generic over `N` as well as `T` in the same way. For example, here is an implementation of `Add`:

```rust
impl<T: num_traits::NumAssign, const N: usize> Add for Vector<T, N> {
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(mut self, other: Self) -> Self {
        for (self_el, other_el) in
            self.elements.iter_mut().zip(other.elements.into_iter())
        {
            *self_el += other_el;
        }
        self
    }
}
```

(It uses a loop instead of `.collect()` because `Iterator::collect()` can't collect into an array, since iterators in general don't have a statically known length.)

Comment: There's also the option of using a boxed slice (`Box<[T]>`) if you need dynamic length, but dont want a `Vec` for some reason. You do then need to handle the case where different length vectors are combined together.